# How to deal with a Haskell package's configured dependency range being out-of-date?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, happstack

When attempting to install happstack via

```
$ stack install happstack
```

I get the following error:

```
    Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-7.2 from implicit global project's config file: /Users/matthewherzl/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml

While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for happstack-7.0.2:
    happstack-server-7.4.6.2 must match >=7.0 && <7.4 (latest applicable is 7.3.9)

Plan construction failed.
```

It appears that happstack requires an older-than-most-recent version of happstack-server. How should I deal with this issue?

---

Potential fixes I've considered:

1. manually change happstack's config on my system, allowing it to depend on the latest version of happstack-config, and assuming that it can.
2. installing an older version of happstack-config.
3. find happstack source repo, validate that it works with latest version of happstack-config, update config to allow it to depend on most recent version, and submit pull request with config change to happstack's central repo.

I am not sure how to do any of these, #3 in particular sounds challenging.

Comment: Cabal is the standard package manager, which provides a more precise control over the package versions, but requires more effort OTOH. Not everyone uses Stack in the community. I know I don't.

Answer (score 3):

*I will initially assume that you are aware of the difference between Hackage and Stackage. If that is not the case, let me know, so that I can explain it in the answer.*

If you go to the [Stackage page for LTS 7.2](https://www.stackage.org/lts-7.2), the resolver/snapshot being used by your global configuration, you will see that the package *happstack* is not among the packages of that snapshot. Then, if you check the [Hackage documentation for the *happstack* package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-7.0.2), you will see a note saying that it was "deprecated in favor of happstack-server". That being so, all you have to do is installing *happstack-server* rather than *happstack*. (A general advice for such situations is always checking the documentation in Hackage and/or Stackage, as it can give a clearer picture of what is going on, as well as extra information on the package versions and dependencies that might be causing yo trouble.)

---

A few words on the three alternatives you thought of. If you have an old package that only needs trivial changes (say, bumping dependency bounds -- if the changes are more substantial you might be better off looking for an older, compatible snapshot) to be built with a recent Stackage snapshot, approaches #1 and #3 are not only good ideas but explicitly supported by Stack. [As explained in the Stack documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/) (look for `packages`, `extra-dep` and `extra-deps` options), you can configure your project so that, rather than the default versions in a Stackage snapshot, you use different versions from e.g. Hackage, a local Git repository or a remote Git repository. If you ever need to do #3 to adjust some package, you don't even need to wait for upstream to accept your pull request -- just configure Stack to pull the dependency from your fork in GitHub or elsewhere.